# Confusing closed form for $\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(x^{2n+1})}dx$ for $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Given that $n\in\Bbb N$,
$$f(n)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(x^{2n+1})}dx$$
How can one get to a closed form of $f(n)$? According to the [online integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/),
$$\int e^{x^{2n+1}}dx=\frac{-\Gamma(\frac{1}{2n+1},-x^{2n+1})}{(2n+1)(-1)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}}+C$$
Which I have no idea how to derive.

Comment: Do some research on the incomplete gamma function. I don't have time to write out the answer sorry.

Comment: If you want to find the value of the definite integral, substitute $t=x^{2n+1}$ and use the definition of gamma function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x^{2n+1}=-u$ or $x=-u^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$ then 
$$dx=-\frac{1}{2n+1}u^{\frac{1}{2n+1}-1}du$$
therefore
$$f(n)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(x^{2n+1})}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\frac{1}{2n+1}u^{\frac{1}{2n+1}-1}du=\frac{1}{2n+1}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\right)$$

Comment: You know a solution is good when it makes you feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome dear.